# Lecture doubt about inscribed angle theorem circle

Tags: circles

So i was watching this lecture on Circle theorems and the professor was talking about this angle inscribed theorem he said

> The angle subtended by the arcs at center is always exactly twice the angle subtended at the circumfence. *That works even if we're looking at two points at either end of a diagonal*, which is the case, it's easy to forget.

i am totally confused, what two points and diagonal he was talking about help me please.
i have lecture video if you want i can post YouTube link its a 4 min lecture

Comment: He may have meant "diameter" rather than "diagonal", in which case the corresponding statement is that a triangle inscribed in a semicircle, with one side the diameter, is a right triangle.

Comment: That's possible, Sir can you take a look at this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWJFA512-jA&feature=youtu.be) @1:04 please